# How to Insert Pictures into Comments of a cell by a given cell name

Tags: excel, vba

**Thanks to Macromarc This Problem has been resolved**

The problem i had with my code was it was only putting in the picture to a cell, and the picture was sized incorrectly. When i filtered my data the pictures always collapsed into each other and it did not look too great.

Below is the correct code that will work for you thanks to Macromarc

[image]

```
     Private Sub GrabImagePasteIntoCell()

    Const pictureNameColumn As String = "A"     'column where picture name is found
    Const picturePasteColumn As String = "J"     'column where picture is to be pasted
    Const pathForPicture    As String = "M:\Users\Dan\Pictures\LabPics\"    'path of pictures

    Dim pictureFile         As String
    Dim pictureName         As String 'picture name
    Dim lastPictureRow      As Long   'last row in use where picture names are
    Dim pictureRow          As Long   'current picture row to be processed
    Dim picturePasteCell    As Range
    pictureRow = 3 'starts from this row

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet    'replace with better qualification
    lastPictureRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, pictureNameColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    'stop screen updates while macro is running
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'loop till last picture row
    Do While (pictureRow <= lastPictureRow)
pictureName = ws.Cells(pictureRow, pictureNameColumn).Value2
If (pictureName <> vbNullString) Then
    'check if pic is present
    pictureFile = pathForPicture & pictureName
    Set picturePasteCell = ws.Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn)

    If (Dir(pictureFile & ".jpg") <> vbNullString) Then
        insertPictureToComment pictureFile & ".jpg", picturePasteCell, 41, 41

    ElseIf (Dir(pictureFile & ".png") <> vbNullString) Then
        insertPictureToComment pictureFile & ".png", picturePasteCell, 100, 130

    ElseIf (Dir(pictureFile & ".bmp") <> vbNullString) Then
        insertPictureToComment pictureFile & ".bmp", picturePasteCell, 100, 130

    Else
        'picture name was there, but no such picture
        picturePasteCell.Value2 = "No Picture Found"
    End If
Else
    'picture name cell was blank
End If

pictureRow = pictureRow + 1
    Loop

    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit_Sub:
    ws.Range("A10").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

    Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error encountered. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    GoTo Exit_Sub

    End Sub
```

The function below handles the insertion of generic images to a cell's comment shape:

```
    Function insertPictureToComment(pictureFilePath As String, _
                        pictureRange As Range, _
                        commentHeight As Long, _
                        commentWidth As Long)

    Dim picComment As Comment
    If pictureRange.Comment Is Nothing Then
        Set picComment = pictureRange.AddComment
    Else
        Set picComment = pictureRange.Comment
            End If

    With picComment.Shape
        .Height = commentHeight
        .Width = commentWidth
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Fill.UserPicture pictureFilePath
    End With

    End Function
```

Comment: Hi, I can't give a thorough answer, but the code to insert an image to a comment is : `myRange.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg"`

Comment: I tried to throw it in there and change up some wording, but its not working out for me.

Comment: I had some time to look at this, and tested a sub

Comment: Hi Danny, is the example answer helping at all?

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Been using it for 4 hours now. Wow did this make my work days easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote some of the other code, and refactored out a function.

Tested and it is basically working for me. Any questions ask:

```
Private Sub GrabImagePasteIntoCell()

Const pictureNameColumn As String = "A"     'column where picture name is found
Const picturePasteColumn As String = "J"     'column where picture is to be pasted
Const pathForPicture    As String = "M:\Users\Dan\Pictures\LabPics\"    'path of pictures

Dim pictureFile         As String
Dim pictureName         As String 'picture name
Dim lastPictureRow      As Long   'last row in use where picture names are
Dim pictureRow          As Long   'current picture row to be processed
Dim picturePasteCell    As Range
pictureRow = 3 'starts from this row

On Error GoTo Err_Handler
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet    'replace with better qualification
lastPictureRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, pictureNameColumn).End(xlUp).Row

'stop screen updates while macro is running
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'loop till last picture row
Do While (pictureRow <= lastPictureRow)
    pictureName = ws.Cells(pictureRow, pictureNameColumn).Value2
    If (pictureName <> vbNullString) Then
        'check if pic is present
        pictureFile = pathForPicture & pictureName
        Set picturePasteCell = ws.Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn)

        If (Dir(pictureFile & ".jpg") <> vbNullString) Then
            insertPictureToComment pictureFile & ".jpg", picturePasteCell, 41, 41

        ElseIf (Dir(pictureFile & ".png") <> vbNullString) Then
            insertPictureToComment pictureFile & ".png", picturePasteCell, 100, 130

        ElseIf (Dir(pictureFile & ".bmp") <> vbNullString) Then
            insertPictureToComment pictureFile & ".bmp", picturePasteCell, 100, 130

        Else
            'picture name was there, but no such picture
            picturePasteCell.Value2 = "No Picture Found"
        End If
    Else
        'picture name cell was blank
    End If

    pictureRow = pictureRow + 1
Loop

On Error GoTo 0

Exit_Sub:
ws.Range("A10").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
MsgBox "Error encountered. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
GoTo Exit_Sub

End Sub
```

The function below handles the insertion of generic images to a cell's comment shape:

```
Function insertPictureToComment(pictureFilePath As String, _
                            pictureRange As Range, _
                            commentHeight As Long, _
                            commentWidth As Long)

Dim picComment As Comment
If pictureRange.Comment Is Nothing Then
    Set picComment = pictureRange.AddComment
Else
    Set picComment = pictureRange.Comment
End If

With picComment.Shape
    .Height = commentHeight
    .Width = commentWidth
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Fill.UserPicture pictureFilePath
End With

End Function
```